# Spring Data JPA - Not a managed type with external jar with entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two projects in my workspace:

- Project A: Contains a database connection logic, JPA Entities & Repositories (javax.persistance), and Spring Data.
- Project B: Makes reference to Project A as a maven dependency. In this project I have Spring core, but not Spring boot (and I don't want to use Spring Boot since this code will be inside an AWS Lambda Function and it is not needed)

If I run the code in Project B locally from Eclipse, everything works fine. But, when I try to execute the code with AWS SAM or in AWS, it fails saying:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.myComp.pojo`

I had a previous issue, Project B wasn't able to find JPA Repositories but that's now solved, adding this:

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myComp"}, considerNestedRepositories = true, includeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = Repository.class)})`

Now Project B is able to see JPA Repositories but entities are not being picked. But only with the JAR packaged version. In Eclipse works fine.
I've tried with `@EntityScan` but no luck.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.